# Multiply vectors with shape (2,) and (3, 1)

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network, deep-learning, backpropagation

I have this code:

```
import numpy as np


def sigmoid(x):
    """
    Calculate sigmoid
    """
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))


x = np.array([0.5, 0.1, -0.2])
target = 0.6
learnrate = 0.5

weights_input_hidden = np.array([[0.5, -0.6],
                                 [0.1, -0.2],
                                 [0.1, 0.7]])

weights_hidden_output = np.array([0.1, -0.3])

## Forward pass
hidden_layer_input = np.dot(x, weights_input_hidden)
hidden_layer_output = sigmoid(hidden_layer_input)

output_layer_in = np.dot(hidden_layer_output, weights_hidden_output)
output = sigmoid(output_layer_in)

## Backwards pass
## TODO: Calculate error
error = target - output

# TODO: Calculate error gradient for output layer
del_err_output = error * output * (1 - output)
print("del_err_output", del_err_output)

# TODO: Calculate error gradient for hidden layer
del_err_hidden = np.dot(del_err_output, weights_hidden_output) * hidden_layer_output * (1 - hidden_layer_output)
print("del_err_hidden", del_err_hidden)
print("del_err_hidden.shape", del_err_hidden.shape)
print("x", x)
print("x.shape", x.shape)
print("x[:,None]")
print(x[:,None])
print("x[:,None].shape", x[:,None].shape)
print("del_err_hidden * x[:, None]")
print(del_err_hidden * x[:, None])
```

that generates this output:

```
del_err_output 0.0287306695435
del_err_hidden [ 0.00070802 -0.00204471]
del_err_hidden.shape (2,)
x [ 0.5  0.1 -0.2]
x.shape (3,)
x[:,None]
[[ 0.5]
 [ 0.1]
 [-0.2]]
x[:,None].shape (3, 1)
del_err_hidden * x[:, None]
[[  3.54011093e-04  -1.02235701e-03]
 [  7.08022187e-05  -2.04471402e-04]
 [ -1.41604437e-04   4.08942805e-04]]
```

My problem is with this operation: `del_err_hidden * x[:, None]`

Which kind of operation is `*`?

And second, if `del_err_hidden.shape` is (2,) and `x[:,None].shape` is (3, 1), why I can multiply them?

Someone has told me that it is related to elementwise and broadcasting, but I don't understand those terms. Because to do a elementwise multiplication both matrices have to have the same size, and here they don't have it.

Comment: Numpy automatically does `del_err_hidden[None,:]`, so the multiplication is a `(1,2) * (3,1) => (3,2)`

Comment: @hpaulj Isn't it the other way around? `(3, 1) * (1, 2) => (3, 2)` to be mathematically correct

Comment: Broadcasted element wise multiplication is commutative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I'm quoting the [broadcasting rules](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.broadcasting.html#general-broadcasting-rules) from the documentation:

> Two dimensions are compatible when
>     1) they are equal, or
>     2) one of them is 1

You have two arrays of shape `(2, )` and `(3, 1)`.

```
arr1 (1D) shape :      2
arr2 (2D) shape :  3 x 1

#                      ^
#                      |    (c.f. rule-2)

In [24]: err              # shape (2,)
Out[24]: array([2, 4])

In [26]: x                # shape (3, 1)
Out[26]: 
array([[3],
       [4],
       [5]])
```

Since, one of the array dimensions is 1, rules are passed. These arrays are broadcastable and can be multiplied. Next part is *stretching* out the array where `err` becomes, (well **only conceptually**).

```
In [27]: err          # shape (3, 2)
Out[27]: 
array([[2, 4],
       [2, 4],
       [2, 4]])
```

Answer (score 2):

The `*` is just element-wise multiplication. *broadcasting* is the reason it works. In short, when you multiple your column of size (3, 1) (let's call it *x*) with a row of size (2, ) (let's call it *y*), numpy creates a new 3X2 array, where the first column is `y[0]*x` and the second column is `y[1]*x`.

The exact rules of when and how that happens are somewhat complicated. See the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) for details